# Efficiency of using CASE WHEN ... IS NOT NULL vs ISNULL/COALESCE

Tags: sql-server

Consider the following scenario:

- There are three kinds of entities, say `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz`.
- Every `Foo` must be associated with a `Bar` or a `Baz`, but not both at the same time.

The scenario is already implemented in the following way:

- There are three tables: `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz`.
- `Foo` has two foreign key fields: `Bar_ID` and `Baz_ID`.
- Exactly one of those foreign key fields must be `NULL`.

Now I would like to build a query displaying the list of `Foo`s, including the description of the `Bar` or `Baz` each `Foo` is associated to. Actually, the description of a `Bar` is a quite complicated formula of the fields of the corresponding row in the `Bar` table. The same applies to `Baz`.

My current query looks like the following:

```
SELECT    Foo.*,
          CASE
            WHEN Foo.Bar_ID IS NOT NULL THEN
              -- a formula, say...
              ISNULL(Bar.LotNumber + '-', '') + Bar.ItemNumber
            WHEN Foo.Baz_ID IS NOT NULL THEN
              -- another formula, say...
              ISNULL(Baz.Color + ' ', '') + Baz.Type
          END AS 'Ba?Description'
FROM      Foo
LEFT JOIN Bar ON Bar.Bar_ID = Foo.Bar_ID
LEFT JOIN Baz ON Baz.Baz_ID = Foo.Baz_ID
```

Is the preceding query is more, less or equally efficient than...

```
SELECT    Foo.*,
          ISNULL( -- or COALESCE
            ISNULL(Bar.LotNumber + '-', '') + Bar.ItemNumber,
            ISNULL(Baz.Color     + ' ', '') + Baz.Type
          ) AS 'Ba?Description'
FROM      Foo
LEFT JOIN Bar ON Bar.Bar_ID = Foo.Bar_ID
LEFT JOIN Baz ON Baz.Baz_ID = Foo.Baz_ID
```

...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, the CASE shlould be because only one expression is evaluated. Several chained ISNULLs will all require processing.

However, you'd need to have a large (10000s of rows) dataset to notice any difference: most processing goes into the actual table access, JOINs etc.

Have you tried it? You can use SQL profiler to see CPU etc for each query.

Comment: I have almost no data to work with, but I do know this will be used in an environment where the amount of data makes efficiency relevant.

Comment: It's a good point.  I didn't consider the number of expressions nested in the ISNULL block.

Comment: +1 - Also `NULL` processing is pretty quick in general so it would definitely take a large dataset to be noticable

Comment: @Eduardo León: you need to test on realistic data volumes then. Otherwise, don't bother. If you don't have (covering) indexes for the JOINs etc then it won't make any difference because all resources will be on table/index scans

Answer (score 1):

I believe that ISNULL is more efficient.  CASE statements are always evaluated first and I believe restrict the options available to the query optimiser.

What does the execution plan say? Is that your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

`COALESCE` is an `ANSI` function while `ISNULL` is an `SQL Server` proprietary function.

They differ in type handling and some other things, and `COALESCE` may accept more than two arguments.

For your task (two arguments, both `VARCHAR`) they are equivalent.